# How physics opens a knife with a flick of the wrist?

Tags: classical-mechanics

A person holds the handle of a folding knife in their hand with the pivot point of the blade between their index finger and thumb. The blade points away from the body and the other fingers grip the handle in a way not to impede the opening of the blade. The friction at the pivot point is just enough for the blade to not open by gravity. The wrist rotates 120 degrees horizontally as fast as humanly possible, accelerating throughout the motion. Then the rotation stops as fast as humanly possible. Shortly after the  rotation stops the folding blade has swung open 180 degrees at the pivot point and locks in place.

Question what physics force(s) opened the knife?

Observation: The heavier the blade the easier it is to open with a flick of the wrist

[Folding knife http://www.digitalcanoe.ca/flick.jpg](http://www.digitalcanoe.ca/flick.jpg)

Comment: What are your own thoughts about this?

Comment: It is called "conservation of angular momentum". One generates angular momentum with the wrist, and its conseration goew to the blade rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the example of a passenger in a car. When the car is moving in uniform motion (acceleration = 0) the passenger is not moving relative to the car. However if the car slows down or speeds up, the passenger begin to resist the motion of the car (i.e. car slows down passenger moves forward relative to the car). [Newton's first law]

Now picture the blade as the passenger and the handle as the car. When you accelerate the handle to the right the blade is resisting that motion and is moving toward the left relative to the blade, however the pivot point forces the blade into the handle.

When you bring the blade to a stop, you accelerate it to the left, making the blade move right relative to the blade. This pivot point forces the blade to rotate upwards.

Comment: I like the your practical explanation.
Would you say that angular / rotational acceleration caused angular / rotational momentum.
Once the acceleration stopped and rotational speed rapidly approached zero, the angular / rotational momentum was converted to torque thereby rotating the blade relative to the handle.
I wish to very clearly understand the forces at work as I believe the answer will cause law makers on three continents to have to rethink the interpretation of their laws.